# how to get cucumber html report like jenkins report running all scenarios in local

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, cucumber-java

i used this code in cucumber options (plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber.json","html:target/CucumberTestReport.html"})
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7I0g.png)
i want a report like Jenkins html report

i want jenkins html report by running all scenarios locally
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppGGW.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

at first install publish html plugin on your jenkins then use it:

```
     publishHTML( target:[
                  allowMissing: false,
                  alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
                  keepAll: true,
                  reportDir: 'your dir',
                  reportFiles: '*.html',
                  reportName: 'HTMLReport', 
                  reportTitles: 'reportTitle']
                  )
```